# Avoid overfitting in 3 layer neural net for cifar10

Tags: deep-learning, overfitting

I made a neural net with 1 conv and 2 fc layers. I am getting 80-90% accuracy on train set but 60% on train set. I used batchnorm layer too but it didn't remove the overfitting. How can I remove it without increasing the layers?

Comment: Try using dropout layers with a dropout percentage of 20% or more.

Comment: I did, didn't help